# ld: library not found for -lPods in XCode

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to build a project that was developed around sept 2015. Getting the following error when run on device,

```
ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I have Podfile.lock which has the version of the libs was being used back then. But I am using latest Cocoapods (v 1.21.1). Assuming this could the problem, I installed Cocoapods (v 0.39.0) that was the version back then. But having following error,

```
[!] Unable to load a specification for plugin `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.1`
Updating local specs repositories 
[!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 1.0.0 - (currently using 0.39.0)
Update CocoaPods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.
```

So I installed CocoaPods (v 1.0.0) but getting the same error,

```
ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Update**
Here is the podfile content,

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
# source 'git@bitbucket.org:****dev/****-ios-spec-pod.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
#source 'https://bitbucket.org/****dev/****-ios-spec-pod.git'

# to test Pod :path => '~/Documents/...'

xcodeproj '****/****.xcodeproj'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

target "****" do 
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'APAvatarImageView'
pod '****-iOS-SDK-API', :path => '~/Documents/****_dev/****-ios-sdk-api-pod'
pod 'PSAlertView'
pod 'UITextField+Shake'
pod 'HexColors', '~> 2.2.1'
pod 'TSMessages'
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
pod 'DateTools'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'PureLayout'
pod 'SZTextView'
pod 'ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum', '~> 1.3'
pod 'UIActionSheet-Blocks', '~> 1.0'
pod 'DTPickerPresenter', '~> 0.2.0'
pod 'CCMPopup'
pod 'FranklySDK'
pod 'Instabug'
pod 'MZTimerLabel'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
end
```

Here, **** = My project name

Comment: do you dun pod update  command

Comment: try command `rvm use system` then restart terminal and try to `pod install`

Comment: Could you show me file Pod?